# Docker/Linux users

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, permissions, devops

I have this scenario: couple of services communicating between each other as docker containers on the client location, locally. Some of the containers are running official images, and the rest of them are running the images that I have built. I haven't defined any user in the dockerfiles yet, because I have hard time understanding what I need to set.
My plan is to run the environment by docker-compose.

I am using bind mounts for almost every service, and I want them to be accessible locally only by "XY" user/ "XY" group.

So far I have created "XY" user and group locally, and I have set desired permissions on the directories that are going to be used by the docker containers. (I have predefined the directories, because there are some files that needs to be mounted into the containers, from the host). Also, I have set permissions on docker command, so it would be able only for "XY".

My question is: what I need to define so I can dynamically set "XY" user to run the services?

I have searched for solution, but haven't recognized anything suitable for me, very possibly due to lack of understanding the problem.

Comment: You can set `user: <uid>:<gid>` on your docker-compose service. Many official images already support this, but others don't. 
Take a look into the [nss_wrapper](https://cwrap.org/nss_wrapper.html) API and [the --user notes of postgres' docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres)

Comment: Docker isn't necessarily a great match for a shared multi-user system: anyone who can run any `docker` command can access and manage any container, and can use that to basically trivially root the host.  Do you need a bind mount for _every_ service?  When you say "accessible", what sort of access patterns are you considering?  What does your current Compose setup and filesystem permissions look like, and what's unsatisfactory about it?

Comment: @David Maze Thank you, I am aware that this is not 100% secure, but in my case it is the best option. I need a bind mount for 3/6 services. When I say accessible.. I want to prevent the client and people working on  the client machine from accidentally or intentionally messing my settings up. They *should* be ignorant of doing so, but I want to put some dosage of security.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, containers are ran as `root`. Docker allows you to change that.

#### Docker-Compose

You can set `user: <uid>:<gid>` on your docker-compose service.

#### Docker Run

Docker run has a `--user` argument that, again, takes in `<uid>:<gid>`.
See

### Availability

Many official images already support this, but others don't.

If you want to adapt this for yourself, take a look at the [nss_wrapper API](https://cwrap.org/nss_wrapper.html) and the [arbitrary --user notes](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) of postgres' docker image

### Docs

What I just explained is also outlined in the docs: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#user